# TFS auto-create subtasks (links) within the work item

Tags: tfs, automation

"A  problem found in software i.e: version 5. Tracing back, this problem exists in previous versions in requirements.  Program Manager (PM) will approve which version should be fixed."

I created 4 WITs called: Main Task, Version Task, Requirements Task, SW Task

I NEED HELP:

- On Main Task: the user selects version(s). Assign to PM.
- PM approves for the selected version(s)
- The Version Task links must be auto-created depend on the selected versions.
- Within each Version, Task must have  Requirements Task and SW Task links, which also auto-created.

Note: all of the above happens at the same time right after the "Approve" button is clicked.

Comment: I don't understand what question you're asking. You've provided a list of requirements.

Comment: Make sure to show the community what you've tried. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for assistance.

Comment: Sorry for not making the points clear.  I use TFS to create the above, but failed at the sub-tasks auto-creation.  So my question: is there any other methods to use for WIT.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t such feature in TFS. The workaround is that you can do it programming:

1. Build an application (e.g. web api) to create work items and add links programming
2. Create a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) for work item updated event, specify your app’s API URL

Some articles about create work items programming:

[Create Work Item in Team Services Through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711796/create-work-item-in-team-services-through-api)

[TFS API Part 22 – Create Link Between Work Item (Parent, Child etc…)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/)

Simple code to create work item and add links:

```
var u = new Uri("team project collection url");
            string projectName = "team project";
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")));

            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            WorkItemStore ws = tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore)) as WorkItemStore;
            var project = ws.Projects[projectName];
            var taskWit = project.WorkItemTypes["Task"];

            var requirementsTask = taskWit.NewWorkItem();
            requirementsTask.Title = "Requirement";
            requirementsTask.Save();

            var SWTask = taskWit.NewWorkItem();
            SWTask.Title = "SW";
            SWTask.Save();

            var versionWit = taskWit.NewWorkItem();
            versionWit.Title = "Version";
            versionWit.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(requirementsTask.Id));
            versionWit.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(SWTask.Id));
            versionWit.Save();
```

If you are using higher version of TFS, you also could custom extension to do it programing: [Extend the work item form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-workitem-extension?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thank you.  I will follow your advice.  Will keep you updated soon.

Comment: @SeekAdvice feel free to post your issue here.

Comment: Thank you  @Starian Chen for your help.  How do I make a call within TFS xml from your simple code?
I am reading the info from your provided links

Comment: @SeekAdvice You need to create webhook.