# How to Auto create a User Story for every new Feature created in TFS

Tags: tfs

How to Auto create a Review User Story (Review US: ….) for every new Feature created in TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't build-in feature to achieve this in TFS at present. The workaround is that you can do it trough programming:

1. Build an application (e.g. web api) to create work items and add links programming  (Parent-Child)
2. Create a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) for work item updated event, specify your app’s API URL

Some articles about create work items programming:

[Create Work Item in Team Services Through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711796/create-work-item-in-team-services-through-api)

[TFS API Part 22 – Create Link Between Work Item (Parent, Child etc…)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/)

Simple code to create work item and add links:

```
var u = new Uri("team project collection url");
            string projectName = "team project";
            VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.WindowsCredential(new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")));

            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(u, c);
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            WorkItemStore ws = tpc.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore)) as WorkItemStore;
            var project = ws.Projects[projectName];
            var taskWit = project.WorkItemTypes["Task"];

            var requirementsTask = taskWit.NewWorkItem();
            requirementsTask.Title = "Requirement";
            requirementsTask.Save();

            var SWTask = taskWit.NewWorkItem();
            SWTask.Title = "SW";
            SWTask.Save();

            var versionWit = taskWit.NewWorkItem();
            versionWit.Title = "Version";
            versionWit.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(requirementsTask.Id));
            versionWit.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(SWTask.Id));
            versionWit.Save();
```

Hope this helps.