# Azure DevOps - Create a work item from incoming email

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm in the process of setting up an in-house Azure DevOps environment. But I'm stuck at a point where I need to set up an email integration.

Question: is it possible within Azure DevOps to create a work item (in general/specific to a project) upon receiving an email?

*Trigger*: Users report issues via a generic email address (like support email)

*Manage*: Azure DevOps to capture this email (monitor inbox of this generic email address)

*Output*: A new work item is created with the contents/subject from the captured email.

Note: Issues could either be a bug, minor usability or other supports

- I did look into MS Power Automate using flow. But not ideal in my
  case
- Searched market place for a possible plugin. But couldn't find one
  which does this

Thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks you for all fellow contributors who suggested alternative approach. Unfortunately, these suggestions doesn't solve my concern at its level and hence I raised a feature request in [Azure DevOps Server](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/tfs.html?type=idea) forum. You may find the request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/964222/create-a-work-item-from-incoming-email.html) and please vote it if you think it is relevant to you.

Comment: Upvoted.  I'd also recommend upvoting the related 'reply via email to discussion' feature:

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Allow-reply-via-email-to-discussion/930157?entry=suggestion&space=8&preview2=true

Answer (score 4):

Azure DevOps does not contain feature to create work items through email. You can try:

1. [TeamBox](https://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teambox/features/email-address-monitoring.aspx) (pop3)
2. As you mentioned MS Power Automate or Azure Logic App.
3. Create your solution with existing resources. As example: [Mail.dll - .NET email component (IMAP, POP3, S/MIME)](https://www.limilabs.com/mail), [Create Work Item in Team Services Through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711796/create-work-item-in-team-services-through-api)

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will try this and other solutions. I shall mark it as the answer once I verify.

Comment: I did tried as you suggested. Especially monitoring inbox and creating work items. I was able to monitor inbox and could see email flowing through. However, I couldn't create work item since there is no API found to work with Azure DevOps Server. Can you advise ? Meantime, I registered a feature request in MS.

Comment: The TeamBox site doesn't use SSL so it won't show up properly in some modern web browsers.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to use the [TFS Work Items from Outlook](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GOTMO.CreateTFSWorkItemsfromMSOutlook) tool.

It's give you the ability to create a work item from outlook and also create rules for create work items automatically (with templates).

[image]

*Note: the name is **TFS** Work Items but it should works also with ADO.*

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will try this and other solutions. I shall mark it as the answer once I verify.

Comment: This add-in works. But it is slowing outlook down often and especially when grabbing work.

Comment: Hi if you have a feedback on this add-in please reach out to me. I created this add-in for Outlook. Since 2020 the add-in has gone through significant performance improvements and should provide a much better experience now.

Comment: Is this free? its asking me for a licence

Comment: @Nikhil, any chance that this tool would be converted to a stand alone service that doesn't require a copy of Outlook?

Comment: @Dennis I am not sure what you mean. Are you looking for a stand alone Windows Application to create work items in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Yes, I can't setup Outlook on my servers to integrate incoming mail with my DevOps server.

Answer (score 2):

As **Shamrai Aleksander** mentioned above, for now Azure Devops Service doesn't support creating WITs from email.

Not sure if above extensions shared by **Shamrai Aleksander** and **Shayki Abramczyk** meet your needs well, I think you can also consider posting a feature request if you do want such feature comes true in Azure Devops Service. Since it's a good idea, feel free to suggest a feature to [User Voice Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) of ADO.

Your requirements seems to be similar to [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/407664/autocreate-work-item-via-email.html) which is posted in 2019, I recommend you can post a new one to share your feedback. Also, share the link in your question and members who interested in that would vote for you! Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and I posted a feature request as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use case for a Logic App. You can create an app that triggers on a new email, using the [Outlook connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#triggers), and then create a work item using the [DevOps connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/).
You can also add logic in the middle (using the Control connector and variables, for instance), to assess the content of the email and dynamically set the target project, work item type, or tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Microsoft Power Automate to do that.

You activator would be receiving an email and the rest of the workflow is up to you. It creates issues correctly and there is even a workaround to add files to the issue with power automate.